# SMTP настройки домена

Tags: smtp

SMTP сервер , не важно гугловский или свой отправляет почту только на домены .com , я подозреваю необходима менять настройки самого домена?

Кто что подскажет?
Установлена панель лицензия ISP Manager 5 lite

Comment: Лог smtp-сессии с гугловским smtp.gmail.com (если речь об этом), есть?

Comment: Извиняюсь, я больше девелопер чем сис, где можно посмотреть? в логах исп  это где-то фиксируется?

Comment: Обычно приложение для реализации клиента (E)SMTP использует какой-то инструмент - либу, пэкидж, модуль. У инструмента должна быть возможность включить дебаг и залогить сессию.